# How do you stop a timer inside it's own tick function?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a problem, where I want to stop my timer inside it's own function, bit for some reason, it doesn't work:

```cs
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timer1_able)
    {
       Random rnd = new Random();
       int length = buttonListforBot.Count();
       int number = rnd.Next(1, length);
       buttonListforBot[number].PerformClick();
       label1.Text = counter.ToString();
       if (counter == 2)
       {
           timer1_able = false;
           timer1.Stop();
       }
}
```

So when I stop it, for some reason, it goes back to itself, and loops trough again

Comment: Exactly Which timer are you using? System.Timers.Timer or 
System.Windows.Threading. DispatcherTimer

Yea according to the signature seems to be the second.
According to the documentation:
"Remarks
Setting IsEnabled to false when the timer is started stops the timer.
Setting IsEnabled to true when the timer is stopped starts the timer.
Calling Stop sets IsEnabled to false."

Comment: Another issue may be that you need to clean and rebuild your project. (of course xD)

Comment: Are you sure `counter` is equal to 2?

Comment: The Timer is set to stop if `counter == 2`, but what sets this is nowhere to be seen. Specify when this happens -- You don't need `timer1_able` at all -- The Random object needs to be declared as a static Field, not inside the `Tick` handler. @rufw91 That's a System.Windows.Forms.Timer (same signature, different assemblies), probably a Timer Component, given the name used.

Comment: I think counter is never equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

This will be fine:

```
int counter = 0;

button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e){
  counter = 0;
  timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   
   counter++;
   label1.Text = counter.ToString();

   if (counter >= 2)
   {
       timer1.Stop();
   }
}
```

You don't need extra booleans to control if some code runs; the Tick event doesn't fire for a stopped timer

Use `>=` for your counter check; it's safer than using `==` just in case one day some code addition means that the counter jumps past 2 and misses it. Always use ranged checks not exact equality checks where possible